# Как запускать тег video от стороной кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста не могу понять как мне запускать тег video(а именно видео в нем ) через отдельную кнопку .Просьба скиньте пример кода или материал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого воспользуйтесь методом [HTMLMediaElement.play()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play) на DOM-элементе видео.